# Copying Attributes And Text From Xml Files, Possibly Putting in Sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

I've been working on a way to parse hundreds of documents for the text which usually have attributes(paragraph) that separate themselves into paragraphs(phrase). This is the way they're usually separated:

**Note: there's a namespace** :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UFT-8'?>
<doc xmlns="http://namespace.com/here/poems">
    <properties>
        <titles>
          <title>Name of Work</title>
        </titles>
        <authors>
         <author>John Smith</author>
        </authors>
    </properties>
    <work>
        <paragraph name="i1">
          <phrase> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br/> consectetur adipiscing elit,<br/>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</phrase>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph name="b1">
          <phrase>A quick<br/>brown fox</phrase>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph name="b2">
          <phrase>Jumps over<br/>the lazy</br>dog</phrase>
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph name="c1">
          <phrase> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br/> consectetur adipiscing elit,<br/>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</phrase>
        </paragraph>
    </work>
</doc>
```

The text is usually kept together in a paragraph by the name of the attribute(b1 is paired with b2, adding a line before and after the text, separating it from the text from differing attributes), so for example, **this would be the desired output:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

A quick
brown fox
Jumps over
the lazy
dog

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

All multiples of the same type of attribute([b1,b2,b3,...][i1,i2,i3,...],etc) should be paired together, being separated by a line.

All of them are in different in the amounts and order of the attributes.
Is there a way to keep that format intact(c attributes together, line in between, b's together, line in between, etc)? I've been messing with the idea of sets as a way of keeping them together but am unsure of the idea.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Comment: Please post sample code if you want people to help with a specific issue.

Comment: What do  you mean by "keep that format intact"? Given your sample xml, what's your desired output?

Comment: Edited! Sorry if I wasn't clear enough! @JackFleeting

Comment: Got it; but how do you "know" to pair b1 with b2 (and not, for example, with c1)? Is that because they start with the same letter (b), or some other criterion?

Comment: yes! All of the phrases that have the same starting letter for the attributes in 'paragraphs' should be paired together. @JackFleeting

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long, but it does work, at least for the text in your question:

```
poetry = """
[your xml above; note that `the lazy</br>dog` should be `the lazy<br/>dog`]
"""
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.fromstring(poetry.replace("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UFT-8'?>", "").replace(' xmlns="', ' xmlnamespace="'))
phrases = doc.xpath('//work//paragraph/phrase')

lines = []
hold = ''
for p in phrases:
    line = ''    
    cfl = p.getparent().attrib['name'][0]    
    if p.getparent().getnext() is None:
        for t in p.itertext():  
            if t not in hold:
                line+= hold+' ' + t+' '          
        lines.append(line.strip())      
    else:        
        nfl = p.getparent().getnext().attrib['name'][0]             
        if cfl == nfl :
            for t in p.itertext():  
                if t not in hold:                    
                    hold+= t+' '                   
        else:
            for t in p.itertext():  
                if t not in hold:
                    line+= hold+' ' + t+' '       
                    hold = ''
            lines.append(line.strip())                  
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,   consectetur adipiscing elit,  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

A quick brown fox  Jumps over  the lazy  dog

Lorem ipsum2 dolor sit amet,   consectetur adipiscing elit,  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```